# JSON file has been read?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, canvas

I am programming a HTML application. It is a pixel art map automatic generator. Reading a JSON file where the map is described using defined tags (wall, roof, grass, three), it draws on a HTML canvas. I'm doing a basic test. But it doesn't work :(

Here's the code of the JSON file, which describes the image to draw:

```
"map" {
    "width": "400",
    "height": "300",
    "wall": {
        "width": "100",
        "height": "100",
        "brick": "01",
        "brick_width": "30",
        "brick_height": "30",
        "x_pos": "50",
        "y_pos": "30"
    }

}
```

And this is the code of the application.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>EXAMPLE</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.getJSON("example01.json", function(dat) {
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            canvas.width = data.map.width;
            canvas.height = data.map.height;

            var wallImage = new Image();
            wallImage.src = "./brick01.png";

            wallImage.onload = function() {

                var wallPattern = ctx.createPattern(wallImage, "repeat");

                ctx.fillRect(data.map.wall.x_pos, data.map.wall.y_pos, data.map.wall.widht, data.map.wall.height);
                ctx.fillStyle(wallPattern);

            }

        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, I use jQuery for `.getJSON;` and for drawing, `.fillStyle`.

But this code doesn't work. When open the HTML file in my browser (Mozilla Firefox 29), the canvas is not draw. The browser just open a blank page.

What is the problem? Does the HTML does not read the JSON File?

Comment: Have you checked the developer console for any errors?

Comment: there's too many possible points of failure: did you actually read the json file from the server? did it have syntax errors? did something blow up in the JS? You need to do some basic debugging yourself, and for this kind of thing, your FIRST stop should always be the browser's debug/devel console.

Comment: The json file is in my computer, in the same folder of the html file.

Comment: @belmart "*The json file is in my computer*" If you're trying this with `file://`, that can be the problem. Ajax isn't typically allowed with it. Setup a local HTTP server to host the page and JSON file.

Comment: You haven't added the canvas to the page.

Comment: Solved, but doesn't work. It seems that Jonathan Lonowski is right. The problem is the JSON File hosted in my computer u.u Set a local HTTP is not suitable. JSON has great advantages, but its implementation is really hard. Im turning to XML, thanks

Comment: It works! It seems that the problem was the pattern created with the image. I do:

Answer (score 0):

you write dat then you use data

Try This

```
var json=$.parseJSON('{"map": {"width": 400,"height": 300,"wall": {"width": 100,"height": 100,"brick": 1,"brick_width": 30,"brick_height": 30,"x_pos": 50,"y_pos": 30}}}');
canv(json);
function canv(data) {
    var newCanvas = $('<canvas/>',{
                       'class':'radHuh',
                        id: 'myCanvas'                    
                    }).prop({
                        width: data.map.width,
                        height: data.map.height,

                    });
     var newImg = $('<img/>',{
                        id: 'myImg'                    
                    }).prop({
         src:"http://hamzaalayed.com/images/icon_skills.png",


                    });
     $('body').append(newCanvas);
     $('body').append(newImg);
     var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
     var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
     var wallImage = document.getElementById("myImg");
     wallImage.onload= function() {
                var wallPattern = ctx.createPattern(wallImage, "repeat");
   ctx.rect(data.map.wall.x_pos,data.map.wall.y_pos,data.map.wall.width,data.map.wall.height);

    ctx.fillStyle=wallPattern;
    ctx.fill();
   };

}
```

Comment: not well-formed example01.json:1
TypeError: ctx.fillStyle is not a function examplecanv.html:33

Comment: There are typo error check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DeveloperH/LCuLS/)